# How do I write a simple program to show a notification when CAPS LOCK is pressed?

Tags: keyboard, notifications, popup, keystroke, keylogger

Forgive me if this is a silly question but I am a novice programmer, and I'm hoping there is a novice solution to this.

Is there any programming language that will quickly allow me to write a simple program to show a notification on Windows 7 when CAPS LOCK is pressed?

My laptop doesn't have an indicator light and I have no program on my computer to do so, although I'd be open to suggestions. The only partial solution I've found is through accessibility settings in Windows which plays a god-awful beep every time the key is pressed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Auto Hotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It is a great program just for that. It runs scripts in the background that can directly manipulate your keyboards input.

I changed capslock to require ctrl+capslock to work otherwise pressing capslock by itself does nothing :)

You can also do a bunch of other things. You are able to set a custom tone for when you push capslock (however a simple popup or key remapping would probably be best).

Here's an example from the site:
"Capslock::Ctrl   Makes Capslock become a Control key. To retain the ability to turn Capslock on and off, also add the remapping +Capslock::Capslock (this toggles Capslock on and off when you hold down the shift key and press Capslock)."